# First principles assessment of Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, probability, regularization, overfitting

I am looking at some machine learning algorithms at the moment, namely logistic regression and simple neural networks.

It seems that the only way that people restrict this is to check for bias and variance in the errors and check this way if it is overfit. Or vary $\lambda$ (the regularisation parameter) to adjust overfitting/underfitting.

Are there any methods which use first principles instead of merely observing the effects. I.e. looking at the number of roots that a polynomial can create and knowing that by the input amount of information that it is more probable than not that this model achieved low error by virtue of replicating information than and actually modelling the link.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a type of "hypothesis testing" at the full model level. That kind of reasoning is in fact used with things like the ANOVA F test, I don't know if there's some general approach that's model independent.  I do think though that the desire to make good predictions is a perfectly reasonable first principle in itself, even if it may not have much theoretical content.

Answer (score 1):

The question of (over)fitting only applies to a specific dataset. If you use hypothesis-free methods like neural nets, it's because you have no idea of the structure of that dataset. Adopting a principled way of setting the model parameters is only possible if you have prior information (or hypothesis) on the data structure, in which case there are more powerful methods than ANNs. Empirical approaches (training and validation subsets, etc) follow from the choice of an unconstrained fitting method.

Comment: "Adopting a principled way of setting the model parameters is only possible if you have prior information" ... Is that strictly true? In the case of a Bayesian semi-/non-parametric approach the parameterisation of the prior is learned to some degree from the data. Admittedly some algorithmic presumptions are required.